# populating jquery datatables from local array of objects

Tags: jquery, arrays, datatables

i have a global variable containing initially an empty array. From user-supplied data, I populate this variable with an array of objects. I'd like to populate a datatables from this array. I am using the following configuration at the top of the document ready, but when the array is populated, the datatables doesn't display the data. `number`, `count` and `percent` are the key names in the objects.

```
                $('#my-data-table').dataTable({
                    paginate: false,
                    data: myArrayOfObjects,
                    columns: [
                        {data: "number"},
                        {data: 'count'},
                        {data: 'percent'},
                    ],
                });
```

I'm certainly populating the array, and I've tried to redraw the datatables with `$('#my-data-table').DataTable().draw();` to no success after populating the local array. What am I missing? Using jquery.datatables 1.10.12-dev

Comment: Not clear if array is populated already at the point you initialize plugin or not. A better outline of process flow would help

Comment: sorry, i thought it was clear that the array is initially empty, the datatables is set up, and then the array populated from user input

Comment: Ok.. and populated how from user input? you need to use the datatable api methods to add a row

Comment: if i set the data-table data property to the variable, why do i manually need to add a row? shouldn't changes to the variable be reflected in the datatable?

Comment: I doubt plugin is going to parse array again since it builds it's own internal data store of both raw data and html. You could use server side fetch approach also

Comment: @charlietfl is exactly right. This is your problem. What does `myArrayOfObjects` look like? I would turn this array into a JSON object (I prefer doing this for datatables) and each time the object (stored in a `var`) you can redraw the table. First thing though is finding out if you're sending valid data into datatables.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var data = [{"number": "1","count": "12","percent": "13",}];
$('#example').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bDeferRender": true,
    "aaData":  data ,
    "aoColumns": [
                { "mDataProp": "number" },
                { "mDataProp": "count" },
                { "mDataProp": "percent" },
{ "mDataProp": "status" }
            ]
});
```